# swap out of memory

Tags: java

I am working on  java application and I have set the following configurations in the VM option

- -Xms and -Xmx options are set to 1024m
- -XX:MaxPermSize=128m  Hardware :32 bit Windows 7 system with 2GB ram.

I often encounter with java out of swap space error. What could be the reason? Please help me.

Comment: Stack allocation? Numpy array allocation? Try with some debug(s) print ... Without code (And I know that maybe you can't post all code) isn't impossible to say

Comment: What more is running on the machine and what is the actual swap space set to? (Computer->System Properties->Advanced System Settings->Performance Settings->Advanced Tab and read what the setting under Virtual Memory is)

Comment: Do you need `-Xms` and `-Xmx` up so high?

Comment: I need -Xms and -Xmx 1024m as application is intended for image and video processing which require intensive memory

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that your operating system is not configured with enough swap space for the job mix that you are running.  Swap space is an area on disc where the operating system puts copies memory pages when there are more virtual memory pages than physical memory pages.

So what has happened is that your JVM has asked for more virtual memory than the operating system can give it.

(Updated to include Peter's comments)

Some possible fixes:

- Add more physical memory assuming that the hardware and OS allow this.  (In this case, the answer the OS *should* allow it ...)
- Configure the system with more swap space.
- Kill some of the other non-essential applications and services running on the machine.
- Change the Java application's JVM options to reduce the heap size.

Comment: +1: Adding more swap space, or run less other applications on the machine.  If you are using 1024M for heap, 128M perm gen and about 150 MB shared libraries etc for Java and 512M for the OS, that doesn't leave much memory for everything else.  Perhaps its time to update the memory if you can. 16 GB can cost less than £100. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The [Java release notes](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/relnotes.html#hotspot) under "Hotspot VM" say about this exact error;

> If you see this symptom, consider increasing the available swap space
>   by allocating more of your disk for virtual memory and/or by limiting
>   the number of applications you run simultaneously. You can also
>   decrease your usage of memory by reducing the value of the -Xmx flag,
>   which limits the size of the Java object heap.

In other words, your machine is doing too many other things using up memory to be able to supply the 1GB you're telling the Java VM that it should be able to use.

Comment: +1. We've monitoring the recurring failure patterns for a short while, the timing of failures helped us discover a couple of daily reporting jobs managed by the Spring Quartz scheduler as part of our tomcat app. The JVM ms/mx options are at 4G, which is high, but only 2 swap space are allocated. With these couple of issues addressed, the failures never show up again.