# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : Out of swap space : Analysis with GC logs

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I got

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 1136136 bytes for Chunk::new. Out of swap space?
>
> Internal Error (allocation.cpp:272), pid=16889, tid=150817680 Error: Chunk::new

In GC logs :

990.772: [GC 990.772: [ParNew: 172602K->15442K(176960K), 0.0488380 secs] 493872K->340757K(2601792K), 0.0492530 secs] [Times: user=0.18 sys=0.05, real=0.05 secs]

29074.961: [GC 29074.961: [ParNew: 176960K->19648K(176960K), 0.0442200 secs] 1022856K->872041K(2601792K), 0.0445530 secs] [Times: user=0.24 sys=0.01, real=0.05 secs]

`493872K` reaches upto `1022856K`.

My Mem options are :

`"-Xmx2560m -Xms2560m -XX:NewSize=192m -XX:MaxNewSize=192m -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:MaxPermSize=64m"`

Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [swap out of memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645609/swap-out-of-memory)

Comment: @Narendra : 493872K reaches upto 1022856K. Is this expected !!

Comment: Yes it may happen if your application is using good amount of memory. The application was not provided with requested swap space and so outofmemory

Comment: @ Narendra : it is continuously increasing.Is this a suspect of memory leak..

Comment: @VJS: Try the suggestions from this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119/how-to-find-a-java-memory-leak

Comment: That's a really small NewSize/MaxNewSize for a 2560m heap isn't it?  New will be further divided into two survivor spaces.  Just sayin...

Answer (score 0):

Check how much available/free space is there in your RAM. Most likely your memory parameters must be exceeding available RAM space. Reduce your memory configuration appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If it continuously increasing then it is definitely a memory leak.

1. Take a heap dump - `jmap -dump:format=b,file=cheap.bin <pid>`
2. Open it in [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/) (free trial) or [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/)
3. Find the biggest object in the heap - that would be your leak :)

Comment: recently I have found short tutorial about all oom problems http://progrnotes.blogspot.com/2015/12/javalangoutofmemoryerror-8-symptoms.html